# Samaung S7 locked out

Tags: locked-out

My new s7 has been locked and it doesnt let me use my fingerprint aince it restarted. i have tried to use android device manager to lock the phone. it sends instruction to the phone and when I enter the temporary password it doesnt accept and goes back to the same message ; try again in 60 mins, I am not able to use find my phone feature as I havent added my samsung account to my phone when I was able to use it.
Please help

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Booting into recovery and doing a factory reset is pretty much your only option.
To get into recovery:
Press and hold “Volume UP + Power + Home” button together and as soon as you see Galaxy S7 Boot logo, release all three buttons.
When you see an exclamation mark on screen, press and hold Power button and hit the Volume Up button once.
Then select factory reset and go thru all the setup again..